# _Nullable method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have a method:

```
- (NSString*)convertName;
```

And then I do something like:

```
- (NSString*)convertName {
    if (![myName isEqualToString:@"someString"]) {
        return NULL;
    }
    .......
}
```

Why the compiler is letting me do this if I didn't specify _Nullable?

Comment: First all. Use nil instead of NULL as it is standard. And _Nullable is simply annotation to give users of understanding that returned pointer can be nil.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, if your methods are either:

- Not declared within a `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`/`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` block
- Not declared *explicitly* with `_Nullable`/`_Nonnull` parameters/return types

then the compiler will not enforce non-optionality. In this case optionality is implied (which is the opposite of Swift, where optionality must be explicitly stated), but in an *unsafe* way.

You can see this if your method above is represented in Swift – it would be shown as being declared like so:

```
func convertName() -> String!
```